# kotlin: retrofit2 getting 404 url not found error

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

Getting Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found, url=https://test.test.com/service/one}

The url is correct as postman works fine.

I have tried looking into this error but most things come back with URL was in correct. and the error itself is vague.

code that starts it. the builder is a json string that is valid. I have tested it in postman.

```
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {

        val call = submitService.submitCarton(builder.toString())
        Log.d("submit", "begining")
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            if (call.isSuccessful) { 
                Log.d("submit",call.body() as String)

            } else {
                Log.d("submit", "else....")

            }
        }
    }
```

service factory:

```
    fun makeSubmitService() : SubmitService{
    val url =  "https://test.test.com/service/"
    return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url)
        .client(okHttpClient).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build().create(SubmitService::class.java)
}
```

interface:

```
interface SubmitService {
@POST("one")
suspend fun submitCarton(@Body json: String): Response<myModel>
}
```

Expected results are a json response however I am not getting that far.

edit: I created a okhttpclient and did a request manual and I get a message 200 ok.

code for my test

```
    val JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8")
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    val body = "some json"
    val requestBody = RequestBody.create(JSON, body)
    val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://test.test.com/service/one")
            .post(requestBody)
            .build()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(request: Request, e: IOException) {

            Log.e("test", e.toString())
        }

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun onResponse(response: Response) {

            Log.d("test", response.toString())
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself.

Issue was dumb, retrofit2 was giving 404 even though the web service was returning a error message.

added

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.1'

private val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
    .build()
```

found out retrofit was sending a very unformatted string

```
"{ \"all my json filled with \" }"
```

instead of

```
{ json }
```

fixed it by adding

```
.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
```

to my service factory

for anyone wondering why I am basically creating the json as a string instead of using a JSON object is because the service I talk to really really wants it to be in a very specific order which JSON just don't care about it however it wants it to look like JSON as well...